# Dash graph with javascript clientside callback

Tags: javascript, python, callback, plotly-dash

I'm struggling to get 2 traces on a plotly graph when updating the data from a javascript clientside callback.

I have this clientside callback:

```py
app.clientside_callback(
    ClientsideFunction(
        namespace='clientside',
        function_name='update_rms_graph'
    ),
    Output('rmstrace-graph', 'extendData'),
    (
        Input('client-rms-data', 'data'),
        Input('client-rms-2-data', 'data'),
        Input('timer-refresh-rms-fft', 'n_intervals')
    )
)
```

Which is defined as such:

```js
window.dash_clientside = Object.assign({}, window.dash_clientside, {
    clientside: {
            update_rms_graph: function(data, data_rms, n_intervals) {
                console.log(data.rms.length, data_rms.rms.length);
                return [
                    {y: [data.rms],  x: [data.t]},
                    //{y: [data_rms.rms],  x: [data_rms.t]}, // This is where i'd like to add my new trace
                    [0],
                    data.max_points
                ]
            }
    }
)
```

The 'rmstrace-graph' is defined as such:

```py
html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='rmstrace-graph', figure=fig_rmstrace),
], className='six columns')
```

And the corresponding figure used for the dash graph is the following:

```py
fig_rmstrace = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergl(y=[], x=[]))
```

How should the 'return' from the clientside callback be wrote if I like to get a second trace from the same dash graph ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
return [
                    {
                        y: [rms.rms, averaged_rms.rms],
                        x: [rms.t, averaged_rms.t],
                    }
                    [0, 1],
                    rms.max_points
                ]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).